# Альтернатива переопределения enum

Tags: java, selenium

Стоит задача парсить неск. десятков сайтов, большая часть селекторов которых идентична. Различаются в основном по тегам.

У меня есть шаблон реализующий скелет парсера, допустим:

```
enum CSS { 
     SEARCHPAGE_URL("https://ya.ru"),
     ...;
}

import static MyPackage.CSS.*
    class siteParser {
        void loadMainPage() {
            getDriver().navigate().to(SEARCHPAGE_URL.toString());
            assertEquals(getDriver().getTitle(), MAIN_PAGE_EXPECTED_TITLE);
            ...
            }
```

мне нужно инода переопределять селекторы т.е. как бы я делал если можно было наследоваться от enum

```
enum CSS2 extends CSS {
    SEARCHPAGE_URL("https://google.com"),
    ...;
}
```

В голову приходят два варианта реализации нужного поведения:
1. Определить общий интерфейс для перечисления, и переопределять метод toString() в потомках где будет сидеть большой switch - что мне не нравится поскольку очень много дублирования
2. Одиночка с полями-строками которые будут переопределятся у потомков

Какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: а что, обычный список строк не годится для такой задачи ?

Comment: годится но неудобочитаемо

Comment: глядя на код енамов выше, может проще тогда просто класс с текстовым полем использовать - несколько реализаций с один интерфейсом ?

Comment: Так и поступил в итоге, только без интерфейса, просто переопределение значений у потомков